# автоматическое скачивание программы с nirsoft

Tags: linux, веб-сервер, utility

есть сайт http://launcher.nirsoft.net/downloads/index.html, там находится программа NirLauncher. При попытке скачать ее wget, aria2c , да и любой программой кроме браузера закачка не происходит. Перевод скачивается нормально, а вот сам архив, нет. Выдает следующий файл

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 
<title>NirLauncher Download Error</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/favicon.ico">
</head>

<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
<div class="topheader">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="topheadertable">
<tr>
<td class="topheaderlogospcleft">
<td class="topheaderlogo" align="left" valign="bottom"><a href="/"><img src="/nirlauncher.png" border="0"></a>

<td>

<tr>
<td class="topheaderlogospcleft">
<td>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="topheadermenutable">
<tr>
<td class="topmenuitem">
<a href="/">Home</a>

<td class="topmenuitem">
<a href="/utilities_list.html">Utilities List</a>

<td class="topmenuitem">
<a href="/downloads/index.html">Download</a>

<td class="topmenuitem">
<a href="/donate.html">Donate</a>

<td class="topmenuitem">
<a href="/screenshots.html">Screenshots</a>

<td class="topmenuitem topmenuitemlast">
<a href="http://www.nirsoft.net" target="nirsoft">NirSoft Home</a>

</table>




</table>



</div>

<div class="toptomain">
</div>

<div class="maincontent">

<h1>
Error 403: Missing HTTP referer in the HTTP request.
</h1>



<p>



</div>

<div class="footer">

</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-6647006-1");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}</script>



</body>


</html>
```

Как это перебороть ума не приложу. Раньше скачивал на автомате, с появлением новой версии, теперь руками

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
wget --referer=http://launcher.nirsoft.net/downloads/index.html <ссылка на дистрибутив>
```

Comment: спасибо, сработало

Answer (score 0):

Там есть такая штука как [pad-файлы](http://nirsoft.net/pad/), которые как раз решают проблему автоматического скачивания. Можно качнуть [zip](http://nirsoft.net/pad/pads.zip) в котором будут xml, а можно дёруть [текстовый файл](http://nirsoft.net/pad/pad-links.txt) в котором будут ссылки на xml в которых будут уже номер версии и ссылки на скачивание и автор и прочее. И не надо парсить html.